# Visual studio development server idle timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, session-timeout

Does the visual studio development server have an equivalent IIS app pool idle timeout setting? If so, how do I change it? I'm having trouble keeping my user's session open while running in a development environment and wonder if this could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ASP.NET Dev WebService does not represent a true production environment, according to Microsoft:

> ... This provides a convenient way to test your ASP.NET application
>   without IIS 7 – however, we recommend that you configure Visual Studio
>   to test your application by using the IIS 7 environment.  The reasons
>   for this are: The ASP.NET Development Server does not support hosting
>   ASP.NET applications in Integrated mode, which is the default mode of
>   operation used by IIS 7. This may introduce differences in application
>   behavior.  The ASP.NET Development Server does not support many of the
>   IIS configuration features, so if your application relies on or uses
>   them, its behavior may be different or incorrect when hosted under the
>   ASP.NET Development Server. The ASP.NET Development Server does not
>   support hosting portions of your application that utilize application
>   technologies other than ASP.NET, such as PHP, CGI, and other third
>   party frameworks.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis/

Comment: Uh, so does it have an equivalent IIS app pool idle timeout setting?

Comment: Hmm, in this case it's bad since it indicates that there's a problem elsewhere. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout in [`sessionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) in the `web.config`:

```xml
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"  />
</system.web>
```

But changes to this value will also get deployed with your application.  Another option would be to use a [conditional compilation preprocessor directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) and override the session timeout on session start in `global.asax`:

```cs
void Session_onStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #if DEBUG
        Session.Timeout = 6 * 60; // 6 hours
    #endif
}
```